# Transfer data between oracle and mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle, symmetricds

I want to transfer data between oracle to mysql via SymmetricDS. Both having same table name but different column names.

Example:

Oracle table structure like

```
om_product
(product_id number,
product_code varchar2(12),
product_name varchar2(240));
```

Mysql table structure

```
om_product
(p_id int,
p_code varchar(12),
p_name varchar(240));
```

I tried via Transform_table and transform_columns. But not able to achieve the objective. Can anyone help me.

Comment: What does *"not able to achieve the objective"* mean? Do you get an error? If so what is it?

Comment: Yes. Not able to transfer the data from master node to child node.

Comment: While running sym command, it rename the actual table structure in child node and create a new table with structure similar like master node

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add any further details or clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Transforms would be the best approach for this use case but you need to be sure you have it configured properly or it will not execute the transform.

Think of the replication process as a workflow where routing occurs then extract transforms then load transforms.    While setting up a transform to fire after routing it is important to setup the source catalog, schema, and table values in the transform to match how routing has output the data (routing target catalog, schema, and table).

There are 3 ways routing can be configured to define the target values:

1.) No values specified in the target catalog, target schema, target table.  In this case your transform should also have an empty source catalog, source schema, and the target table in question.

2.) The router could have the "use source catalog schema" turned on.  In this case you need to set the transform source catalog and source schema to match the value of source catalog and source schema in the trigger.

3.) Finally the router configuration might specify a target catalog, target schema, and target table.   In this case the transform source catalog, source schema, and source table must match these target values in the router.